# Throw a ConfigurationErrorsException when run .net app on ubuntu with mono4

Tags: c#, ubuntu, mono

I wrote and compiled a helloworld app in vs2015rc:

```
namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        protected static readonly NameValueCollection AppSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
        private static readonly string rootDir = AppSettings["RootDirPath"] ?? "";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hello world");
            Console.WriteLine(rootDir);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

when I run this app on on ubuntu with mono4, a `ConfigurationErrorsException` is thrown:

> lijing@ubuntu:~/Desktop/iQQ.Net$ mono Test.exe
>
> Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception
>   was thrown by the type initializer for Test.Program
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Error Initializing
>   the configuration system.
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized
>   configuration section 
>   (/home/lijing/Desktop/iQQ.Net/Test.exe.config line 3)

This is the config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="RootDirPath" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
    <add key="LibPath" value="Lib\win64\"/>
    <add key="DataDirPath" value=""/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

The mono version is: 
**Mono JIT compiler version 4.0.2 (Stable 4.0.2.5/c99aa0c Wed Jun 24 10:04:37 UTC 2015)**